# Need help with a regular expression for Search/Replace in editor

Tags: sql, regex

I am trying to replace all timestamps in a SQL dump with the now() function. All times vary, but the year is always 2010.

I want to replace: '2010-10-0920:40:00.352298-05'
with: now()

Does anyone know what expression I might use with the 2010 being static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest regular expression would be to match any strings starting with 2010, from the opening quote to the closing quote:

```
/'2010-.*?'/
```

This finds strings starting with 2010 and does a non-greedy match to the first quote, which should be the closing quote as the date can't really contain an escaped one.

If this isn't specific enough, you can restrict the type and number of characters matched:

```
/'2010-[-.0-9:]{15,25}'/
```

I can't tell you how to run this regular expression without knowing what editor you're using, but in vim there is a slightly different syntax for non-greedy matching:

```
:%s/'2010-.\{-}'/now()/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
2010-\d+-\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+-\d+
```

or, if the quotes are actually part of the text

```
'2010-\d+-\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+-\d+'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s/2010-.{23}/now()/g
```

since there are 23 characters after "2010-".

Use

```
s/'2010-.{23}'/now()/g
```

if you want to get rid of quotes as well.